Динамический формировать robots.txt
Стал записывать в таблицу бд, url адреса которые возвращают 404 код + 410
Ранее на сайте было 4000 публикаций, оставил 10%. + перед удалением перешел на другой url публикаций(вместео /news-auto-top, стал /n-23123) и тут же стал делать 301 перенаправление с url на конце которых был слеш.
В общем если нырять в говно, то целиком...
Забросил сайт, икс упал, посещаемость упала, так и так...
В последнее время решил доделать... Не о том, спустя год, роботы по-прежнему обходили страницы 404...
Они удаляются, роботы перестают обходить их, но это очень долго. Куда быстрее выставить запрет в robots.

в публикациях были изображения по 2-5, url которых тоже изменил. В общем те карусели...

Стал вести таблицу и записывать url, вижу какие страницы боты посещают с кодом 404, какие не существуют...
sitemap на сайте, формата php. То есть не через крон, сразу отдаю данные бд, все работает..
К вопросу. В гугл консоле, вебмастре нет возможности указать какой файл играет роль robots.txt. Остается только обновлять его по крону...
Что если обновлять robots по крону и выгружать в него таблицу с url адресами несуществующих страниц. Дабы в ручную не добавлять...
Был ли у кого подобный опыт?

если других txt в корне нет и точно не будет, можно сделать хитрее. в .htaccess добавляете AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .txt после чего текстовики становятся полноправными php скриптами включая robots. пихаете в него примерно тоже самое что и в sitemap"е и все дела :3 в публикациях были изображения по 2-5, url которых тоже изменил. чтоб такого не было, прикреплять можно BBcod'ом по id'ам  [file=123] [img=123]. так можно будет тасовать роуты хоть раз в час.

На сервере есть txt, которые подгружаются через js. Возможно ли правило задать таким образом, что единственный txt который будет исполняться как php. Будет с именем robots...,?

не уверн, но скорее всего прямых команд для этого нет. можно лишь косвенно(во первых все txt перекинуть куда-либо из корня, во2 везде кроме корня запретить запуск\открытие txt, или даже deny from all, по ситуации)
